# Cypress testing of redirects to different origins (cross-origin)

Tags: javascript, redirect, cypress, stub, web-api-testing

My web application, on load, automatically redirects the user to a URL on a different origin via the [`window.location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) method based on their user parameters.

When Cypress tests my application and attempts to follow the redirect, it detects the violation of the `same-origin` security policy and the test crashes. But I still need to test that `window.location.replace` is being called correctly.

Based on Cypress's documentation, I believe I need to use [`cy.stub()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/stub) to mock the function, in order to avoid the side effect of the browser actually redirecting to a different origin.

I have tried several different ways to stub `window.location.replace`, but none of them seem to work as I expect.

```
// none of these work

cy.stub(window.location, "replace")
// TypeError: Cannot redefine property: replace

cy.stub(window, "location.replace")
// TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property location.replace

window.location.replace = cy.stub()
// TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'replace' of object '[object Location]'


cy.visit("http://localhost:3000");

expect(window.location.replace).to.be.called;
expect(window.location.replace).to.be.calledWith('https://some-other-origin.com/some/url')
```

I do not believe I want to use [`cy.location()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location) because, by the time the redirect has occurred, the test has already crashed due to the `same-origin` security violation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Deal with window.location.replace](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-tips-and-tricks/#deal-with-windowlocationreplace). The approach is to rename `window.location` in the source, before the page is loaded.

How well this works depends on the structure of your app. If you post some details, I can look at giving a more specific example.

```js
it('replaces', () => {

  cy.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
    win.__location = {                           // set up the stub
      replace: cy.stub().as('replace')
    }
  })

  cy.intercept('GET', 'index.html', (req) => {   // catch the page as it loads
    req.continue(res => {
      res.body = res.body.replaceAll(
        'window.location.replace', 'window.__location.replace')
    })
  }).as('index')

  cy.visit('index.html')
  cy.wait('@index')

  cy.contains('h1', 'First page')
  cy.get('@replace').should('have.been.calledOnceWith', 'https://www.cypress.io')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried relaxing the security policy in your cypress configuration.

There are few options depending on your needs like --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating

A good blog which I found on the topic is : https://medium.com/@you54f/configuring-cypress-to-work-with-iframes-cross-origin-sites-afff5efcf61f

Give it a shot and let me know if it was helpful.

Cheers
Rupesh